# How to form steel truck fenders

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, metal-folding

I want to set up steel truck fenders production line, but have no idea how to do that. Something like this picture.

Edit1:
I have two plans to form final curved shape , using a hydraulic press or using a customized rolling machine .
Final products must have no riples .

[image]

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, although it's also opinion-based.  You do it by buying someone's factory, and moving it to your location.  Or you go to work at someone's factory for about ten years (preferably with a dozen of your friends), and then you all go home with most of the the knowledge you need.

Comment: TimWescott I know the basics and i made some samples using sheet metal bender ,hammer and an English wheel . But i want to know industrial products process .

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your raw material will come in the form of a large spool of sheet metal containing a strip of steel hundreds of meters long. You will need an *unspooler* to feed steel off the spool and a *straightener* to take the curvature out of the steel strip. Then you need either a *punch press* or a *shear* to cut the sheet metal blanks to size and trim their corners. To put ripples or corrugations into the cut blanks, you will need a *roller die* or a *rolling mill*. To put a folded edge onto the sides of the blank you will need either a *bending brake* or a set of *progressive dies*. To bend the fenders into their final curved shape you will need a *sheet metal press* and to smooth out any resulting ripples you will need an *ironing press*.

To attach the mounting brackets you will need an *electric spot welder*. Finally, you will need either an *electrostatic spray booth* to paint them or a *powder coating rig*.